# My query doesn't work if the last query has a comment on it.

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

we've been struggling to some situations in PHP wherein some of the queries don't work. We've found out that the non-working-queries occurs only if the last query executed has a comment in it.

In php, we have something like this:

```
$getUsersQuery = "SELECT * from `users` where active = 1; ##DEVELOPER: JOE";
$getUsersStmt = $con->prepare($getUsersQuery);
$getUsersStmt->execute();
$users = $getUsersStmt->fetchAll();

$getProductsQuery = "SELECT * from `products` where active = 1; ##DEVELOPER: JOE";
$getProductsStmt = $con->prepare($getProductsQuery);
$getProductsStmt->execute();
$products = $getProductsStmt->fetchAll();
```

For the `$users` variable, it contains accurate data, but in `$products` variable, it contains nothing. After moments of configuring, we got a theory that it's because the last query executed has comment `##DEVELOPER: JOE` on it. We removed the comment of the first query, and the second query worked. We've tested it, and the theory is proven. Btw, we are using MySql and PHP 5.

> We now know the reason how it occurs. But our question is that, **why is
>   it occurring?**

*If you have ideas, please do comment it out. That will be a big help for us. Thanks.*

Comment: Why are you passing comments into prepare statement ? You can move the comments out of query string, and write them in the application code itself. Passing comments to MySQL server wont serve any purpose.

Comment: Yeah, you don't need to put comments in the query itself.

Comment: We knew our mistake and it's fixed now. Our question is that, why is it occurring?

Comment: @JJLabajo  because it treated as a part of the query and hens error occurred.

Comment: I'm thinking it may have something to do with you not clearing the previous statement or something after you use prepare. Maybe the second query is being put in the same line as the comment of the query above or some weird thing like that. What happens if you do `$getUsersStmt = null` before the second `prepare`?

Comment: @AlivetoDie Thanks, so why is it treating it as part of the query when it is in different variables and the first query has already been executed.?

Comment: @JJLabajo  can you check with `#` instead of `##` that both query worked or not?

Comment: @AlivetoDie # and ## does the same thing.

Comment: @Phiter I like your answer too. Thanks

Comment: @JJLabajo  good question. +1

Comment: @AlivetoDie Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The culprit is not the comment itself. It's the combination of having a `;` statement delimiter, a comment and two different statements. Here's a simpler reproduce code:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT CURRENT_DATE; #');
$stmt->execute();
var_dump($stmt->fetchAll());

$stmt2 = $con->prepare('SELECT CURRENT_TIME');
$stmt2->execute();
var_dump($stmt2->fetchAll());
```

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["CURRENT_DATE"]=>
    string(10) "2018-11-13"
    [0]=>
    string(10) "2018-11-13"
  }
}
array(0) {
}
```

What's probably happening is that PDO believes you're issuing multiple statements thus expects multiple result-sets. If you overwrite the statement it seems to clear stuff automatically but if you create a new variable it seems it's still expecting the first statement to complete.

If you call [`PDOStatement::nextRowset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.nextrowset.php) everything works again:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT CURRENT_DATE; #');
$stmt->execute();
var_dump($stmt->fetchAll());
$stmt->nextRowset(); // <--- Retrieve the "phantom" result-set

$stmt2 = $con->prepare('SELECT CURRENT_TIME');
$stmt2->execute();
var_dump($stmt2->fetchAll());
```

Alternatively, you can set `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false` so PDO will not parse SQL and let the job to MySQL server.

Comment: Oh wow! great knowledge. Can i know the source of this knowledge?

Comment: Flawless! Thanks for enlightening, not just me but, everyone.

Comment: @AlivetoDie I've had problems with PDO in the past and my research eventually lead to the internal SQL parser being to naive for some edge cases. I figured out this could be a similar situation and ran some checks :)

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález  great .+1